# Explain the characteristic features of long range entanglement

Tags: topological-order, topological-phase, entanglement-entropy, strong-correlated

The long range entanglement (LRE) can exist in fermi liquids or lattice. The characteristic features of long range order entanglement could be the degeneracy, fractional excitation or the entanglement entropy. 
Am I right? What are their relations?

Comment: As it is this question is either too broad or not precise enough. What exactly do you not understand ? See https://arxiv.org/abs/1004.3835 or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_order and tell us what you misunderstand there.

Comment: The term "long range order entanglement" is not defined. You need to define it to make your question more clear. The term  "long range entanglement" is defined in https://arxiv.org/abs/1004.3835. According to that definition, a state can have long range entanglement, even without  the degeneracy, fractional excitations or the topological entanglement entropy.

Comment: @Xiao-GangWen thanks for your correction! Since long range entanglement is the core characteristic  of topological order, why people always talk about the degeneracy, fractional excitations and the topological entanglement entropy?

Comment: In 1989, when we introduced topological order in terms of the degeneracy and fractional excitations, the field of quantum information had not taken off yet. I did not know what was entanglement at that time. Only after the introduction of topological entanglement entropy in 2006, we start to realize that topological orders are just patterns of long range entanglement.